# Updating django model form values upon a change in a separate form value

Tags: python, django, django-models, geolocation

I (first-time programmer) am attempting to create a site with django where one feature is that the admin can add locations and relevant information (like coordinates) to a feed.

The goal of this is to allow the admin to enter in the latitude and longitude of a location into the admin site manually. However, if this isn't done, the program should attempt to generate these values via the use of a geocoder and the address field. This works fine, so far. But what I'm trying now is to automatically update those values whenever the address changes. The boolean refreshCoords should be set to true when the address model is changed. However, I get this error upon submitting the admin form:

```
AttributeError at /admin/network/nonprofit/add/

type object 'Nonprofit' has no attribute 'changed_data
```

I'm not sure what to do now. I'm using the changed_data method from the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data. How can I update the data like this? Is there another way, or am I using the wrong method? Below is the relevant code in python models.py:

```
class Nonprofit(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Each nonprofit belongs to one network
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter the nonprofit address, if applicable", null=True, blank=True)

    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null = True, blank=True)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, null = True, blank=True)
    refreshCoords = models.BooleanField(default="False") #GOAL:if this is true, I want to change the coordinates with the geolocator using the address

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'self.address' in Nonprofit.changed_data: #check to see if the address had changed
            self.refreshCoords = True

        try:
            if self.address and self.lon==None: 
                #If there is an address value but not a longitude value, it correctly sets the longitude with the geocoder and address
                #This part doesn't really get used with respect to the "refreshCoords" part because this is the initial (no change yet) setting of the coordinate value
                self.lon = geolocator.geocode(self.address, timeout=None).longitude

            if self.address and self.lat==None:
                self.lat = geolocator.geocode(self.address, timeout=None).latitude

            if refreshCoords: #if the address has changed, then refresh the coords
                self.lon = geolocator.geocode(self.address, timeout=None).longitude
                self.lat = geolocator.geocode(self.address, timeout=None).latitude
                refreshCoords = False #after the coordinates have been updated with the new address, don't update them until the address is changed again to save loading time
        except geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut:
            print("The geocoder could not find the coordinates based on the address. Change the address to refresh the coordinates.")

        super(Nonprofit, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```py
if 'self.address' in Nonprofit.changed_data:
```

The class `Nonprofit` doesn't have such property.

You're probably thinking of `Form` instance, which has such property, but is not available in that place.

Also, the `Nonprofit` is a type. The instance you're saving is called `self` in your snippet.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And that form instance would go in forms.py, and I would be able to use it on the admin site?

Comment: Correct. You need to override this model's admin (lookup `register` in Django admin app context) with the one that contains ModelForm with overwritten `save`. Then this will also be available on `self`.